# What is best practice with Firestore snapshot listeners when app enters background?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I couldn't find any documentation on best practices with Firestore snapshot listeners when the app enters the background, should they be removed (and re-enabled when the app enters the foreground)? Or is it perfectly fine practice to leave them listening when the app is in the background? And if the app is in the background long enough, does Firebase ever kill them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to leave the listener added, you should be aware know that it could continue to consume resources while the user isn't using the app.  Eventually the OS will shut off the app's ability to do networking, and kill the app process.

For Android, if you won't want the listener to trigger after the user leaves the app, you should remove it during onStop, which signals that the fragment or activity is no longer seen by the user.  So, you will probably want to use onStart to resume the listen when the user comes back.

Comment: Is this only an issue if the listener is receiving updates while the app is in the background? If the app is in the background with the listener running without ever receiving updates, is the listener still a potential threat to getting the app killed?